# About rotations in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I'm developping a simple code, trying to learn some OpenGL. I did a simple square with `GL_LINES`, and I tried to rotate them with arrow keys. When it's about rotating left and right, it goes well, but if I try to rotate it up and down it jumps sometimes. I know the mistake is on this line, but I don't know how to fix it: `if(beta>=PI*2.0 && beta<=0) beta=0;`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define INCREMENTO .1
#define DISTANCIA 50
#define PI 3.1416

float alpha=0;
float beta =0;

void myCamara() {

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-100.0,100.0f,-100.0,100.0f,-100.0,100.0f);     
    gluLookAt(((float)DISTANCIA*(float)sin(alpha)*cos(beta)), ((float)DISTANCIA*(float)sin(beta)), ((float)DISTANCIA*cos(alpha)*cos(beta)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);


}

void myTeclado(unsigned char tras,int x,int y)
{
    switch (tras) {
    case 'l':

    break;
    case 'c':
            break;
    case 'r':
            break;
    case 'p':

    break;

    default:
    break;
    }

  glutPostRedisplay();
}

 void myTeclasespeciales(int cursor,int x,int y) 
{
    switch(cursor) 
    {
        case GLUT_KEY_F1:
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_F2:   
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_F3:           
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_F4:
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_F5:           
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_F6:       
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_UP:
            beta-=INCREMENTO;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            beta+=INCREMENTO;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            alpha-=INCREMENTO;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            alpha+=INCREMENTO;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if(alpha>PI*2.0 && alpha<=0) alpha=0;
    if(beta>=PI*2.0 && beta<=0) beta=0;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: I assume you are trying to keep your alpha and beta angles between 0 and 2*pi, right? Try using the remainder (%) operator on your angle value. If your angle is greater than 2*pi, the remainder (beta % 2*pi) will be positive and should work. If the remainder is negative (which might occur in the case of a negative angle), then just add 2*pi to the remainder result!

Comment: It wont help on your problem, but you could define `DISTANCIA` as `50.f`, and use `cosf` and `sinf` to remove casting and improve readability.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon I don't get it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If statements will never  be true:

```
if(alpha>PI*2.0 && alpha<=0) alpha=0;

if(beta>=PI*2.0 && beta<=0) beta=0;
```

You need or ( || ) not and (&&).

The problem is not only on beta.

The solution is

```
if(alpha>PI*2.0 || alpha<=0) alpha=0;

if(beta>=PI*2.0 || beta<=0) beta=0;
```